# React route rendered component not triggering setState on parent

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have an issue with React Router v.4. When a route is matched in the parent component and the child component is rendered, the componentDidMount method of the child triggers the showAlbum method passed to it by the parent.

However, though the showAlbum method is triggered, the setState method inside it does not update the state of the parent. When the child component is unmounted, the showAlbum method works correctly, just as it does on the subsequent calls.

Any idea where do I go wrong?

Thank you!

Parent component:

```
export default class AlbumContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      showAlbum: false
    }
  }

  showAlbum() {
    this.setState({
      showAlbum: !this.state.showAlbum
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="border">
        <div className="u-innerContainer">
          <Route path='/:linkName' render={ (props)=><Album showalbum={ this.showAlbum.bind(this) }/> } />
        </div>
      </section>
    )
```

Child component:

```
export default class Album extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <div className="u-innerContainer">
          <Link to="/">Back</Link>
          <h3>{ 'title' }</h3>
          <section>{ 'content' }</section>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.showalbum()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.showalbum()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry, I haven't got time to verify the solution, but your problem can be caused by setting of state based on previous state value.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

Try to set new state by this way:

```
showAlbum() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        showAlbum: !prevState.showAlbum
    }));
}
```

Comment: Hi. Yes. I checked the new state with setState's callback function and it shows the updated state. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `constructor` in Child component :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}
```

Comment: I did. But the described behavior doesn't change. Now I also get a console warning: Useless constructor  no-useless-constructor

Comment: Will you please create a plunker or jsfiddle for this?